# Changing WooCommerce cart item names

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

The goal is to change the name of the item as it gets passed to our payment gateway, but leave it as-is for display on our product pages.

I've tried this in my functions.php:

```
function change_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
    $item_name = 'mydesiredproductname';
    return $item_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'change_item_name', 10, 1 );
```

But it doesn't seem to be working for me.  I feel like I should be passing in an actual item ID or something… I'm a little lost.

Any information on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The **`woocommerce_order_item_name`** filter hook is a front-end hook and is located in:

**1) WooCommerce templates:**

- emails/plain/email-order-items.php
- templates/order/order-details-item.php
- templates/checkout/form-pay.php
- templates/emails/email-order-items.php

**2)WooCommerce Core file:**

- includes/class-wc-structured-data.php

> Each of them has $item_name common first argument, and different for the other arguments. 
>  See [Here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_order_item_name) for more details…

You have 2 arguments set in your function (the second one is not correct for all templates) and you are declaring only one in your hook. I have tested the code below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'change_orders_items_names', 10, 1 );
function change_orders_items_names( $item_name ) {
    $item_name = 'mydesiredproductname';
    return $item_name;
}
```

And it works on

- Order-receive (Thank you) page,
- email notifications
- and My Account Orders > Single order details

**But NOT in Cart, Checkout and Backend Order edit pages.**

> So if you need to make it work on Cart and Checkout, you should use other hooks like **`woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`**.
>  Then you can use [**`WC_Product methods`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_set_name) (setter and getters).

Here is your new code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_items_prices( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        // Get the product name (Added Woocommerce 3+ compatibility)
        $original_name = method_exists( $product, 'get_name' ) ? $product->get_name() : $product->post->post_title;

        // SET THE NEW NAME
        $new_name = 'mydesiredproductname';

        // Set the new name (WooCommerce versions 2.5.x to 3+)
        if( method_exists( $product, 'set_name' ) )
            $product->set_name( $new_name );
        else
            $product->post->post_title = $new_name;
    }
}
```

Code goes in any php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin php file.

**Now you have change the names everywhere except on Shop archives and product pages…**

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce 2.5+ and 3+

> If you want **to keep original item names in cart only** you should add this [conditional WooCommerce tag](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-8) inside the function:
>
> ```
> if( ! is_cart() ){
>     // The code
> }
> ```

This answer has been updated on August 1st 2017 to get a woocommerce compatibility prior versions…

Comment: Thanks! This still works. But what if you want it to get changed only on back-end site when an admin views the order, and not in cart/checkout/email and so on?

Comment: You may have also be looking for woocommerce_cart_item_name

Comment: Doesn't work. I have tested it.