# Changing WooCommerce item name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I don't have 50 reputation on stack overflow, so I can't comment on post. To ask a question I gotta make a new question unfortunately :/

So, from here :
[Changing WooCommerce cart item names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44994359/)
OP asked about changing WooCommerce cart item names.

The answer below, which
@https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec 
reply helped me but it isn't complete enough..

I've tested the code he gave,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_items_prices( $cart_object ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Iterating through cart items
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        // Get the product name (item name)
        $id = $cart_item['data']->get_name();

        // THE NEW NAME
        $new_name = 'mydesiredproductname';

        // Set your cart item name
        $cart_item['data']->set_name( $new_name );
    }
}
```

it works great, for the code above on the cart page, checkout page customer invoice page and admin order page is changed to "mydesiredproductname" but I want the Cart Page, the Checkout Page, the customer invoice page and the admin order page to remain the same, only thing is changed is the item name that is submitted to payment gateway. Wonder if that is possible? Or what is the closest that I can achieve?

ps: I tested `is_cart` and also `is_checkout` function, for is_cart the cart is unchanged, for is_checkout the checkout page is unchanged.

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks !

Comment: Please elaborate by giving a more detailed example and describe exactly what steps you took and what didn't work as expected.

Comment: I used this code by @LoicTheAztec

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_items_prices( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Iterating through cart items
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        // Get the product name (item name)
        $id = $cart_item['data']->get_name();

        // THE NEW NAME
        $new_name = 'mydesiredproductname';

        // Set your cart item name
        $cart_item['data']->set_name( $new_name );
    }
}

Comment: They worked great but I want the Cart Page, the Checkout Page, the customer invoice page and the admin order page to remain the same, only thing is changed is the item name that is submitted to payment gateway.

Comment: This is too complicated as it depend of the payment gateway integration available hooks (I think)… You can look at the [function `process_checkout()` in WC_Checkout source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#895)… but is not going really to help you. The changes to make are in your related payment gateways code.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec , I wonder if it is possible to make the code run when the gateway is selected during checkout? In that way everything will work as normal until the gateway is selected? I believe that might be the closest that I can achieve?