# Change WooCommerce variable product title based on variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

I've coded in a custom select box to a group of my products that changes the price based on the user's selection. It works well, but now I need to change the product title too based on their selection.

Basically if option 1 is chosen, the product name stays the same. But is option 2 is chosen, I need to add "-RZ" to the end of the product title.

I'm not sure if I can do this in the 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' hook where I altered the prices, but if anyone knows the hook I should use and the code to access the current product's title via PHP that would be great.

Here is the code that alters the price if it's helpful:

```
function calculate_core_fee( $cart_object ) {
    if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {
        /* core price */

        //echo $additionalPrice;
        //$additionalPrice = 100;
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            $product_id = $value['product_id'];
            if( isset( $value["addOn"] ) && $value["addOn"] == $product_id) {                
                    $additionalPrice = $value['core'];
                    /* Woocommerce 3.0 + */
                    $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->get_price() );
                    //echo $additionalPrice;
                    //echo $orgPrice;
                    $value['data']->set_price( $orgPrice + $additionalPrice );

            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_core_fee', 99 );
```

I know may have to get the name and store it in a SESSION variable to use later if the hook to do this is on the cart, checkout, or order page rather than the single-product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes this is possible in the same hook**. You can manipulate the product title with class [**`WC_Product`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) [**`get_name()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_name) and [**`set_name()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_set_name) methods. But as for the price, you should set and get a custom cart field value to make it *(just as `$additionalPrice = $value['core'];`).*

See here a simple related answer: [Changing WooCommerce cart item names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994359/changing-woocommerce-cart-item-names/44994871#44994871)

So you could have something like *(just a fake example):*

```
// Get your custom field cart value for the user selection
$userSelection = $value['user_selection'];
// Get original title
$originalTitle = $value['data']->get_name();
// Conditionally set the new item title
if($userSelection == 'option2')
    $value['data']->set_name( $originalTitle . '-RZ' );
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you